# is it possible to use a java array in javascript function?

Tags: java, javascript, jsp, servlets, model-view-controller

Im trying to pass an array of strings from a java servlet to a jsp file.
now, i want to use that array in a javascript function in that same jsp file.
is this possible?

Comment: Not directly. JSP is a server side technology. Javascript is a client side technology.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you'll need to convert the array to JSON first though, then have your JavaScript function parse that JSON.  At that point it can work with it as a standard JS array (because at that point, it is).

***EDIT*** - I did not mean to imply that `JSON` is absolutely required, nor that it is the only possible solution. It's simply an option, and in my opinion probably the best and easiest for what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: It doesn't *have* to be JSON, it just has to be valid JavaScript. But fundamentally, yeah.

Comment: .... and there's no need for additional parsing - the JavaScript parser will do the work and the code will have a ready-to-use native JavaScript array.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder What would you suggest, as far as a better approach than using JSON?  Because I fully agree, but I can't think of a better/easier/more efficient approach than using JSON.  If you can, please provide an answer.  If not, I don't think the pedantic nit picking really helps here.  No offense.

Comment: @Pointy *"the JavaScript parser will do the work"* - that *is* the "additional parsing"

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Well, ok. I'd wager 99% of the time "we" would use JSON for this.  I could be wrong.  And I'd be genuinely interested to see an alternative approach here that's *better* than using JSON (because my answer was intended to help op solve their problem, I wasn't intending to be dogmatic about `JSON`)

Comment: @Madbreaks yes, I'm not disagreeing with you. I've seen code that involves stuff serialized to JSON and then string-escaped and dropped into a JavaScript string. That's the sort of crazy stuff we need to avoid in this troubled world :)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder No, that is not what Pointy was saying.  See his/her comment on other answer.  And see his/her response, above.

Comment: @Madbreaks Thank you very much for your answer. I googled it a little bit and could not find an example for serializing a java object and then deserializing it in the client side with javascript. Do you have something?

Answer (score 2):

You'd have to first serialize it (JSON format is probably easiest) and then deserialize it in javascript to be able to use it as an array.

Comment: If it's serialized to JSON it can be dropped *directly* into JavaScript code and used as-is. The JavaScript parser will parse it.

Comment: You may still want to use JSON.parse(<string>) rather than dropping <string> directly into Javascript source code (depending on where <string> comes from) to be able to catch JSON decode exceptions and defend against potential security issues.

Comment: @JoshLiptzin: The array data is clearly coming from a trusted source in this case.